# De serialize the JSON data in wpf

Tags: wpf, json

I have a url which return's json data in the following way

```
{"title":"Test Title","image_url":"http://i.imgur.com/aZO5Kol.jpg","random_window":2,"windows":{"1":{"title":"Random 1"},"2":{"title":"Other Window 2"}},"thankyou_url":"http://google.com"}
```

Now i want to De-serialize this so that i can write the conditions based on the data received.
I want achieve this

[image]

will have to print the image and Name which is received  through JSON. And based on the number of windows i should show the windows

I have declared a class

```
 public class JsonData
{
    string title { get; set; }
    string image_url { get; set; }
    string random_window { get; set; }
    string[] windows { get; set; }
    string thankyou_url { get; set; }
}
```

and i have written like this

```
            WebClient objWebClient = new WebClient();
            var jss = new JavaScriptSerializer();
            string strJsonURL = "url";
            var vJsondata = string.Empty;
            vJsondata = objWebClient.DownloadString(strJsonURL);
             var data = jss.Deserialize<object>(vJsondata);
            try
            {
              var x = ((IList)data).Cast<object>().Select(o => o.ToString()).ToList();
            }
```

But getting this error:

```
Unable to cast object of type 'System.Collections.Generic.Dictionary`2[System.String,System.Object]' to type 'System.Collections.IList'.
```

Comment: that Json does not seem valid

Comment: what issue are you getting?

Comment: I am not able to get in a way that i can access the values by indexing like x[0] like that

Answer (score 0):

It appears that `windows` is a `Dictionary` and not a string array as you have defined in `JsonData`. You'll have to test this but from what I can tell it should be more like this:

```
public class JsonData
{
    string title { get; set; }
    string image_url { get; set; }
    string random_window { get; set; }
    Dictionary<string, WindowData> windows { get; set; }
    string thankyou_url { get; set; }
}

public class WindowData
{
    string title { get; set; }
}
```